# how to make nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I want to make a nested dictionary but I don't know why I am not getting my desired result

```
def stud(data):
    empty_dic = {}
    for line in data:
       empty_dic[line["stud_num"]]={line[course]:line[marks]}
    return empty_dic
data = [
  {
   
    "course": "asd",
    "stud_num": "123",
    "marks": 28
  },
  {
    
    "course": "qrt",
    "stud_num": "123",
    "marks": 27
  },
  {
 "course": "asd",
    "stud_num": "124",
    "marks": 30
  },
  {
   "course": "zx",
    "stud_num": "124",
    "marks": 31
  },
  {
   "course": "zx",
    "stud_num": "123",
    "marks": 28
  }
]
```

output of my code is => `{"123":{"zx":28},"124":{"zx":31}}`

my desired output is => `{"123":{"asd":28,"qrt":27,"zx":28},124:{"asd":30,"zx":31}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use can simply do it by using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

adict = defaultdict(dict)
for obj in data:
    adict[obj['stud_num']][obj["course"]] = obj['marks']

print(adict)
```

Your fixed version (assgin empty dict if there's no line["stud_num"] in the empty_dic):

```
def stud(data):
    empty_dic = {}
    for line in data:
        if line["stud_num"] not in empty_dic:
            empty_dic[line["stud_num"]] = {}
        empty_dic[line["stud_num"]][line['course']] = line['marks']
    return empty_dic
```

**Output:**

```
{'123': {'asd': 28, 'qrt': 27, 'zx': 28}, '124': {'asd': 30, 'zx': 31}}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply i want to ask can we do it without collection.defaultdict because due to some reason i do not want to import collection.defaultdict

Comment: Yes, I've posted a fixed version of your solution

Comment: yeah got it thank you so much i was tring from last one and half hour thank you so much